# I am not understanding what's going wrong in this program please help me?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

// A binary stream is a series of data type values
// To read and write to them you use different methods
// based on the type of data that you are using

public class lesson33{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Create an array of type Customer

        Customer[] customers = getCustomers();

        // A DataOutputStream allows you to print 
        // primitive data types to a file

        DataOutputStream custOutput = createFile("/Users/derekbanas/Documents/workspace3/Java Code/src/customers.dat");

        // Enhanced for loop for arrays
        // Cycles through all of the people in the customers array

        for(Customer person : customers){

            createCustomers(person, custOutput);

        }

        // Closes the connection to the DataOutputStream

        try {
            custOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("An I/O Error Occurred");

            // Closes the program

            System.exit(0);
        }

        getFileInfo();

    }

    // class that defines all the fields for my customers

    private static class Customer{

        public String custName;
        public int custAge; 
        public double custDebt;
        public boolean oweMoney;
        public char custSex;

        // constructor that's called when a customer is made

        public Customer(String custName, int custAge, double custDebt, boolean oweMoney, char custSex){

            this.custName = custName; // String
            this.custAge = custAge; // Integer
            this.custDebt = custDebt; // Double
            this.oweMoney = oweMoney; // Boolean
            this.custSex = custSex; // Character

        }

    }

    // Creates an array of Customer Objects

    private static Customer[] getCustomers(){

        Customer[] customers = new Customer[5];

        customers[0] = new Customer("John Smith", 21, 12.25, true, 'M');
        customers[1] = new Customer("Sally Smith", 30, 2.25, true, 'F');
        customers[2] = new Customer("Paul Ryan", 21, 0, false, 'M');
        customers[3] = new Customer("Mark Jacobs", 21, 3.25, true, 'M');
        customers[4] = new Customer("Steve Nash", 21, 5.25, true, 'M');

        return customers;

    }

    // Create the file and the DataOutputStream that will write to the file

    private static DataOutputStream createFile(String fileName){

        try{

            // Creates a File object that allows you to work with files 
            // on the hard drive. There is no difference between File
            // for character or binary stream writing, or reading

            File listOfNames = new File(fileName);

            // FileOutputStream is used to write streams of data to a file
            // You define whether a new file is created versus appended
            // to based on if you add a boolean to the FileOutputStream
            // FileOutputStream(file, true) : Appends to the file
            // FileOutputStream(file, false) : Creates a new file

            // BufferedOutputStream gathers all the data and then writes
            // it all at one time (Speeds up the Program)
            // DataOutputStream is used to write primitive data to the file

            DataOutputStream infoToWrite = new DataOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(listOfNames)));
            return infoToWrite;
        }

        // You have to catch this when you call FileWriter

        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("eager");
            System.out.println("An I/O Error Occurred");

            // Closes the program

            System.exit(0);

        }
        return null;

    }

    // Create a string with the customer info and write it to the file

    private static void createCustomers(Customer customer, DataOutputStream custOutput){

        try{
        // Write primitive data to the file

        // Writes a String in UTF format
        custOutput.writeUTF(customer.custName); 

        // Writes an Integer 
        custOutput.writeInt(customer.custAge); 

        // Writes a Double
        custOutput.writeDouble(customer.custDebt); 

        // Writes a Boolean 
        custOutput.writeBoolean(customer.oweMoney); 

        // Writes a Character
        custOutput.writeChar(customer.custSex);

        // You also have writeByte, writeFloat, writeLong
        // and writeShort
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("eager 1");
            System.out.println("An I/O Error Occurred");
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

    // Read info from the file and write it to the screen

    private static void getFileInfo(){

        System.out.println("Info Written to File\n");

        // Open a new connection to the file

        File listOfNames = new File("/Users/derekbanas/Documents/workspace3/Java Code/src/customers.dat");

        boolean eof = false;

        try {

            // A DataInputStream object has the methods for reading the data
            // The BufferedInputStream gathers the data in blocks
            // FileInputStream gets data from the file

            DataInputStream getInfo = new DataInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(listOfNames)));

            // Using a while loop that pulls data until EOFException is thrown

            while (!eof){

                // You have to read data in the exact order it was put in the file

                String custName = getInfo.readUTF();
                int custAge = getInfo.readInt(); 
                double custDebt = getInfo.readDouble();
                boolean oweMoney = getInfo.readBoolean();
                char custSex = getInfo.readChar();

                System.out.println(custName);
                System.out.println(custAge);
                System.out.println(custDebt);
                System.out.println(oweMoney);
                System.out.println(custSex + "\n");

            }   
            getInfo.close();
        } // END OF TRY


        catch (EOFException e) {

            eof = true;
        }

        // Can be thrown by FileInputStream

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Couldn't Find the File");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("eager 2");
            System.out.println("An I/O Error Occurred");
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }


}
```

producing output as follows:-

```
eager
An I/O Error Occurred
```

this program was intended to print the customers credentials showing the datainputstream

A binary stream is a series of data type values
// To read and write to them you use different methods
// based on the type of data that you are using

Comment: So what do you think is wrong? You did not tell us.

Comment: You catch, but why don't you print the stack trace? That's where all the info is hiding!

Comment: No way for us to tell when you swallow the exception. Could be anything.

Comment: Try printing the stack trace: `e.printStackTrace()`;

Comment: just guess, your file path is not correct. Add drive letter as well.

Comment: My bet is on `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @Jimmy If he is on Mac, then there won't be a drive letter.

Comment: agreed. What I doubt is, OP being derekbanas. I know that guy make tutorial , so it is probabaly copy paste problem for the path.

Comment: @Jimmy It would be very funny if this is the case :D.

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis:**

Launch in debug mode in IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ). I recreated the error but it is because `fileName` does not exist.

Does this file exist on your system? Are the permissions right on this file? What is in this file?

- /Users/derekbanas/Documents/workspace3/Java Code/src/customers.dat

Is this on a Unix box?

Comment: Thanks for the help got its solution.

Answer (score 0):

reason you are getting like "eager   An I/O Error Occurred" was due to "**java.io.FileNotFoundException: customers.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)**" and your catch block in createFile method showing that error message.

issue is with file location/path.

`DataOutputStream custOutput = createFile("C:\\tmp\\customers.dat");`

please change the the file path accordingly.